# El pegajoso embrollo de traducir "sticky"

Tags: bug, perfil, barra-superior

Ayer [se conversó en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37811819#37811819) cómo traducir la opción "[disable stickiness](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/mine)" referida a la barra superior con el nuevo diseño, pero creo que el término quedó al revés.

Actualmente dice "Inmovilizar barra superior":

[image: Inmovilizar barra superior. Cuando se marque la casilla, la barra de navegador no quiera sujeta a la cabecera de página.]

aunque el comportamiento es que se inmoviliza **cuando se desactiva** la opción.

Algunas opciones para usar:

1. No inmovilizar barra superior
2. Movilizar barra superior
3. No fijar barra superior
4. Ocultar barra superior
5. Deshabilitar *sticky* de barra superior

---

Además, en la descripción, creo que no es "la barra de navegador". Una traducción podría ser:

> Marcando la opción, la barra superior no quedará fija al desplazarse por la página.

---

**Notas**

- Obviamente son términos que tienen acepciones muy variadas según el país, y no tengo problema en que se modifique la traducción que propuse. La idea es que no quede al revés de lo que debería ser.
- Por favor, no me vengan con términos como "pegajosa", porque en lo único que pienso es en cosas como:

  > [image: El Rey León, Simba comiendo un gusano y diciendo "viscoso pero sabroso" | Cazafantasmas, Slimer]

Comment: Esto creo que pertenece más a [spanish.se]. En serio :D

Comment: @fedorqui puede ser una buena pregunta para hacer allá, pero sigue siendo un reporte de bug porque el término usado en la opción es el contrato al comportamiento que se da.

Comment: me gusta la sugerencia que hace @Mariano aquí, si la gente no se opone, la podemos cambiar en seguida.

Comment: Sugerí [No inmovilizar barra superior](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/134815566?key=3246db29064c5ae80409dd15dd3a4104) y [Marcando la opción, la barra superior no quedar…](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/$/134815567?key=e9fb4be4455c6380fefe9802cfe54baf) en Transifex según lo que había propuesto